# Changing remote app.config with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a test library which reads an app.config config key value for a test run which changes from build to build (The app window which has the version number embedded). Another key also changes based on the environment that the tests will hit (dev/test etc).

eg.
    key ="AppVersion" value="AppVersion (1.0.0.19)"
    key ="AppSubVersion" value="Ver (1.0.0)"
    key ="DataDirectory" value="Data - Dev"

Currently, on the local machine, this is not a problem as I manually change them from run to run. However, we are now considering moving to an automated run scenario where the tests are kicked off as part of an automated test run whereby TeamCity server will kick off the tests on the remote machine. Would really appreciate your answer to two questions

1 - Is there a way for TeamCity to change a specific key on an app.config file located on a remote machine ?

2 - If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TeamCity can do that for you.  However if you have TeamCity run a nant script for you, you can use XmlPoke to replace the text in your config file, you can use the current Teamcity build number for the version stamping.  I assume ant has something similar if you want to use ant.